# Is there any way to Write same property name in partial class in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop, partial-classes

My Auto Generated Class

```
public partial class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I want following output. And I don't take same property name in my partial class. so how can i achieve my result? is there any other way.

```
public partial class Address

{
   public string Name  => Name + " ";
}
```

Comment: Why would you want/need this? A partial class is just a way to split up a class. Imagine declaring `Name` twice in the same class. You'd also have a recursive problem in the 2nd one.

Comment: My requirement is that i just need to add space after my Name property value. and my class is auto generated partial class. If i change in one place then i don't need to change in all places in my project.

Comment: Just use a different name then. Like `NameWithTrailingSpace`.

Comment: @Sweeper Then i need to change in whole project. and more than thousand places.

Comment: In your IDE, there should be a feature called "Rename"...

Comment: The generated class is not sealed, so derive a class from it and re-introduce the property with the new modifier. It can call the base method in the new implementation.

Comment: This sounds like UI logic.  It shouldn't be on the database.  Just change in your implementation.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't possible and really doesn't make any sense. A partial class is just a way to split up a single class. In your example, this is equivalent to having

```
public partial class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Name  => Name + " ";
}
```

Which is obviously not going to compile. Even if it did, the fact that `Name` is trying to access itself is going to immediately cause issues.

According to your comment, you just need to add a space to the end of the `Name` property. Since that class is auto-generated, you'll need to add a new property with a different name, such as:

```
public partial class Address
{
   public string NamePlusSpace  => Name + " ";
}
```

Comment: Yes that i know. with use of different property it is possible but it requires lots of changes in my project. so is there any other way that i can achieve?

Comment: @KaranRana none that I can think of without making other types of large changes, unless you can change where/how the generated code comes from. Using the IDE to rename should be pretty easy though.

Comment: thanks. i will make changes in my database property value. i just wanted to is there other way or not? if available then i don't want to change in database.

Comment: @KaranRana - If you're changing the core meaning of the property (yes, even an added space counts) it's not a bad thing at all to have a large change reflected in your source control. And the renaming functionality of Visual Studio should make this quick and nearly painless.

Comment: @KaranRana adding a space at the end of a name sound like UI logic. I think it would be better to not have this in the database and maybe even away from the business objects. This could be in the control or even with css. My assumption here could be totally wrong also.